# Azure Devops - Pipeline does not have permissions to use the referenced service connection

Tags: azure-devops

In my yaml pipeline I get the following error when I try to deploy to an App Service using a Service Connection.

`##[error]Pipeline does not have permissions to use the referenced service connection(s) MyServiceConnectionName. For authorization details, refer to https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.`

In the past when I got similar auth errors (during initial pipeline setup), there was a button to authorize the pipeline to use the Service Connection. This button seems to have been removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipeline permission to a Service Connection can now be configured through the using the service connection security page. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#secure-a-service-connection

[image]